# SE and SD in a mixed ANOVA design

Tags: mixed-model, anova, standard-deviation, standard-error

I have conducted a mixed-design ANOVA with a between-subjects factor (**Group**: Control Group [0] vs. Intervention Group [1]) and a within-subjects factor (**Time**: Baseline [0], Follow-up 1 [1], and Follow-up 2 [2]). To further investigate a significant interaction (Time Point * Group), I performed pairwise comparisons in SPSS. I now receive a table with the **mean** and a **Standard Error** (SE) for each group at each time point.

In the '*Estimates*' table, I now find the means of the respective groups at each time point (for example, the mean of the control group at Time Point 1 [Baseline]). This mean corresponds to the 'ordinary' mean that I could calculate descriptively.

However, in addition, I now find a **Standard Error** in the table, rather than a Standard Deviation. Since the formula for the **Standard Error (SE)** is **SD/sqrt(n)**, I thought that multiplying SE by sqrt(n) would lead me to the original Standard Deviation. However, this is not the case. The Standard Deviation that I find, for instance, in the 'Descriptive Statistics' table is different from when I attempt to calculate it from the provided Standard Error (SE) (using: SE * sqrt(n)).

Can someone tell me why this is the case and why SPSS, in the output of the Follow-Up Tests (Pairwise Comparisons), provides the same means, but the Standard Error (SE) does not match the value I get when I divide the SD by the square root of n (SD/sqrt(n)) [or the other way around: I don't get the same Standard Deviation (SD) when I multiply the SE with the sqrt(n)]?